# Developing a mobile chat room, backend use XMPP or WebSocket?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, websocket, socket.io

Some requirements for a mobile chat room:

1. Should be able to work seamlessly with client's frequent connect/disconnect due to the mobile network
2. Bandwidth saving (less overhead)

I don't have experience in XMPP, I only have worked with Node.JS server and it is easy to setup and hack the server with JavaScript.

But seems XMPP is the defacto standard for chat room, e.g. WhatsApp use them., anyone can share your experience in these two technologies?

Comment: You can also try out MQTT, Facebook is using it for its chat. http://mqtt.org/ , http://www.eclipse.org/paho/

Comment: For developing a chat room using XMPP, You need an XMPP Server (http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) and you need to develop an XMPP Client, You can develop client using libraries(http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) too. XMPP is primarily designed for Chat Applications.

Comment: Hi Howard, StackOverflow isn't the place for sharing experiences. Questions that are chatty or open-ended are generally closed as not constructive. My suggestion is to check out the technologies yourself, and if you get stuck with a more specific problem or question, come back and see us. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Orchestrator - Facebook chat is XMPP (that doesn't mean that MQTT is not used in some fashion within their solution, but it is XMPP chat).

Comment: I agree with @iNan though, you should rephrase your question or it will probably (and rightly) get closed.

Comment: @Robin maybe I should have been more accurate and say "Facebook Messenger" but facebook does use MQTT. http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger  , http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-facebook-messenger/10150259350998920

Comment: Facebook makes use of MQTT to push messages to cellphone, Backend of Facebook Chat is not based on XMPP. However XMPP Clients can connect to Facebook chat server easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are kind of asking how can I get to my destination, should I drive my car, or take the railroad tracks.  If you go with the railroad tracks, you still have to build your train.

XMPP is primarily used for chat and excels in that space.  Websockets is much more similar to BOSH in XMPP, an extension to allow two way communications over HTTP.  Websockets is just a connection protocol, as opposed to a realtime messaging protocol that actually supports the concept of chat.  I would speculate that in the future, there will an extension added to XMPP to support Websockets, as it is a natural fit.

Not saying that you can't use Websockets, just that you will still have to build the 'chat' protocol on top of it, as opposed to using an existing one with many servers readily available.