# Developing Chat/Real time web application

Tags: xmpp, chat, push, polling

I am currently doing my research on building a chat system with more than 10k users connected online. I came across technologies and ways to do it such as jabber(XMPP), websockets, long polling, push. As far as I now, long polling might not work given the number of users. I know there is a lot of ways to accomplish this. I also know that facebook and Google chat systems are developed on XMPP.

I would truly appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction. I believe all these methods and technologies out there are good depending on the scale of the project. I definitely need performance and scalability.

Comment: you might want to look at the server side to solve to C10K problem. One way is nginx with the [http push module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/)

Comment: Thanks Ronalchn! that's what i'm doing. But with all choices out there, it's kind of difficult choosing the most suitable one. Which was the same process I went through when picking a php framework. There were a lot out there but they had limitations such as scalability.

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131760/developing-a-mobile-chat-room-backend-use-xmpp-or-websocket/11142357#11142357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Socket.io](http://socket.io) together with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) for such a chat application. It scaled to over 10K concurrent users on moderate servers and there was a lot of room to grow.

This does depend on your limitations, tho.

- What kind of hardware are you planning on using?
- Which operating system would power your servers?
- Which client platforms are you targeting?
- Do you have an existing infrastructure you need to fit this into?
- Do you have a previously selected programming language?
- The existing skill sets your team members have and your team's ability to adopt new platforms and languages if necessary.

Take all of the above into consideration when making your decision.

Personally, I've found XMPP to be quite adequate, but a bit bloated for my purposes. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lior! I came across Socket.io and NodeJS while doing my research. In the current state: The language being implemented is PHP, the target platform is browsers, servers are most likely Windows powered, and it's a new infrastructure. Based on what I found, choosing the right technology for this type of project is crucial. I have done something small like this before with just ajax. However, I know that in this case it just wouldn't work. Push servers would be the option, no doubt about it. Based on this facts, do you still recommend Socket.io and NodeJS?

Comment: @Charlie: I haven't tried nodeJS on Windows servers before, so I really can't comment on that. Regarding your target being browsers, it seems to me like NodeJS+Socket.io should work fine for that purpose. I really wouldn't try anything push related with PHP if you really need to scale, since PHP doesn't fit into that kind of architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a fruit basket and three different variety of oranges.

XMPP is the only protocol that you have mentioned that actually is designed to support a chat system (of which many exist).  The others are simply asynchronous messaging protocols/techniques.  XMPP already supports http based chat via [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html).  Without a doubt, it will also support WebSockets when the specification is finalized.  There is actually a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-moffitt-xmpp-over-websocket-01) of this already written, but at this point it appears to be a draft using a draft, so there will probably be few, if any, implementations.

Using XMPP would allow you to build on a proven technology for implementing a chat system and would allow you to choose what transport you want to use "under the hood".  You haven't actually said whether you need a http based transport or not, but with XMPP you can use the stock tcp socket based transport or a http based one (BOSH) with the knowledge that it will also support WebSockets in the future.

The other benefit is of course that this is a widely used standard that will allow reuse of [existing clients, servers and libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/) in pretty much all popular (and not so popular) languages and platforms.

Scalability is not too much of a concern with the numbers you are quoting, as most (maybe all) existing xmpp servers will handle that many users.

Comment: Great info, Robin! As you can gather, I'm not an expert with this topic or the approach that needs to be taken to develop such system. However, things are starting to clear up. Based on your answer and research, it appears that I need more than just an http server (ie. apache) and a database to take care of something like this. Which I understand because I tried something similar before with a small project, using apache with Flash Media server (RTMP protocol)  to provide live video streaming over http. It seems  that I need to do a similar thing now. I truly appreciate the info on XMPP!