# Why choose XMPP whereas Node.js and WebSocket is available?

Tags: node.js, websocket, xmpp, chat

I am developing a chat system.

I am asking which is better for backed among:

- XMPP
- Node.js
- WebSocket

Currently I am using XMPP. Is this right or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131760/developing-a-mobile-chat-room-backend-use-xmpp-or-websocket/11142357#11142357

Comment: We have moved from XMPP to socket.io in our application. Now it's much comfortable and have less overhead.

Answer (score 3):

One word: federation!

In practice XMPP is a messaging protocol while node js a framework. Websocket is a transport protocol. That means that you could very well imagine that you use XMPP over Websockets using a Node.js server.

Comment: There is in fact a draft spec for XMPP over Websockets already.

Comment: Link to the XMPP-over-websockets draft: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-websocket-01